# Spring mvc jackson json

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm trying to use JQuery with JSP ang Spring MVC. In the example I'm working on, it is given that,

```
// @ResponseBody will automatically convert the returned value into JSON format
// You must have Jackson in your classpath
```

How to add Jackson to classpath? What is its use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add jackson json library to your build path and web app library. It is required to serialize the POJO to json

Comment: i've added spring-json-1.3.1.jar to the build path. Which other jar files should I include? Is there any other changes to be made?

Comment: I've also added jackson-mapper-asl.jar

Comment: jackson-all-1.6.2.jar is the one I currently use, works fine with Json requests